# I am passing index for dates and not expected dates coming

Tags: android, date, time, days

In code the loop is to get me next week 7 days and add them to the array list.
When I try this I get Mon, Tue, Thu, Sun, Thu, Tue .I don't understand why it is like that. It is not right one.

I need output as Mon, Tue, Web, Thus, Fri, Sat .

According to docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/DayOfWeek) , the numeric value for Monday is 1, Tuesday is 2 and so on.

```
   String dat,day;

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM"); //Date and time

    DateFormat sdf_ = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
    Date date = new Date();


int i=0;

    while (i<7)
    {
         calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
         dat = sdf.format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
         day = sdf_.format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));

        mDate.add(dat);
        mDay.add(day);

         i++;

    }
```

Comment: You are modifying same calendar in each iteration here . if you want to do it like this its has to be `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);.` you can set the calendar to yesterday to get Today inside loop or use something like `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i*1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use 1 instead of i in calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
since you are using the same instance of calendar.

```
int i=0;

    while (i<7)
    {
         calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
         dat = sdf.format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
         day = sdf_.format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));

        mDate.add(dat);
        mDay.add(day);

         i++;

    }
```